# Conflict between Picture model and Ckeditor::Picture model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, ckeditor

In my existing Rails project, I create Picture model.

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

And then, when adding Ckeditor to my project, I have to create another Picture model under ckeditor directory like this

```
class Ckeditor::Picture < Ckeditor::Asset
  ...
end
```

In my user model, I have this association
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_many :pictures
    end

However, I cannot use `user.pictures`. Whenever I make this statement, the following error comes up:

```
Expected /home/xxx/app/models/ckeditor/picture.rb to define Picture
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve my issue by renaming the `Picture` class into `UserPicture` and use `table_name` to set its corresponding table in database. And then in `User` model:

```
has_many :pictures, class_name: 'UserPicture'
```

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :pictures,:class_name=> "::Picture"
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but maybe:

```
module Ckeditor
  class Picture < Ckeditor::Asset
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change Dafault Picture Model Name in `config/initializers/ckeditor.rb` like this:

```
Ckeditor.setup do |config|
  ...
  config.picture_model { Ckeditor::EditorPicture }
  ...
end
```

remove autogenerated defined model from `models/ckeditor/picture.rb` and add  new model `/ckeditor/editor_picture.rb`

insert to `editor_picture.rb`

```
class Ckeditor::EditorPicture < Ckeditor::Asset
  mount_uploader :data, CkeditorPictureUploader, :mount_on => :data_file_name

  def url_content
    url(:content)
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple**:

1) rename `models/ckeditor/picture.rb` to `models/ckeditor/epicture.rb`

2) in `models/ckeditor/epicture.rb` change to this:

```
class Ckeditor::Epicture < Ckeditor::Asset
  has_attached_file :data,
                    url:  "/ckeditor_assets/epictures/:id/:style_:basename.:extension",
                    path: ":rails_root/public/ckeditor_assets/epictures/:id/
```

3) in `config/initializers/ckeditor.rb` uncomment row and change to this:

`config.picture_model { Ckeditor::Epicture }`

4) for correct work in `_asset.html.erb` change [bug](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/pull/584):

`polymorphic_path(asset, format: :json)` to   `picture_path(asset)`

> in my case dir of this file
>   `\usr\local\rvm\gems\ruby-1.9.3-p545\gems\ckeditor-4.1.2\app\views\ckeditor\shared\_asset.html.erb`

Restart server.
Work's fine!